# Changing Eric6 appearance configuration

Tags: python, ide, eric-ide

I'm trying to use Eric6 python IDE and have been struggling with making it fit my needs better. I want to use it as a poor man's Matlab, thus many advanced features are useless to me, plus some programming habits are actively hindered by Eric.

1. can I disable "variable unused" warnings? I've been searching through settings over and over again to no avail. The problem is those warnings "inject" themselves into the code as extra lines which is a real sore for the eyes.
   [image: how it looks like]
   alternatively, it could be a floating text that doesn't shift everything below by one line.
2. Prevent it from switching to Log-Viewer every time I run a script. I just want to use the shell like in Matlab for quick access to variables.

Does anyone have experience with this IDE?

Answer (score 0):

1) The only (*GUI-availeble*) option here seems to be to disable the code checkers part all together.

- [ **Settings** > **Preferences** > *Editor* > *Code Checkers* > Automatic syntax check ]

-- Reload the file to get rid of any lingering code-checker messages.
-- Checked against Eric6 (18.06)